# vertical multilevelmenu slideToggle glitch

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

So I've got a vertical menu with submenus that when the cursor moves over the parent link, the child menu slidesDown. The issue occurs when quickly scrolling between sibling links with the cursor. The animation of any child links of the parents you're browsing flickers between completion and (i assume) initiation. Now I've got stop() and I've tried many iterations of it even including the [queue] (http://api.jquery.com/stop/) value but to no avail.

```
$('ul li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find(' > ul').stop( true, true ).slideDown(700);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find(' > ul').stop( true, true ).slideUp(700); 
        });
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kupdt/

One other issue I've discovered is if you have .stop( true, false) when the same action is performed the animation 'sticks' and doesn't show any more content when initiated again than what it reached at the time the cursor moved to the next parent link originally.

Now, as a simple form of apology, I'm sure that this has been answered somewhere else on this site, simply due to the ease in which I could replicate it. However, I've searched and can't find anything relevant. Probably since I've no idea how you'd quickly phrase the question.

EDIT
In the end this issue wasn't a problem in my case as I was using the menu as part of a responsive 'reformat' for my site when view with smaller screens. Due to the fact these devices hardly ever have a hover system similar to mouse pointers, the issue doesn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.queue()`

Try:

```
$('#block-menu-block-1 li.expanded ul').slideUp(0);    
$('#block-menu-block-1 li.expanded').hover(function () {
    $(this).find(' > ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(700).queue(function () {});
},    
function () {
    $(this).find(' > ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(700).queue(function () {});
}).queue(function () {});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kupdt/2/)

Comment: Sorry but this hasn't fixed the issue. At first it seemed that the glitch was fixed in IE and chrome, when viewing it in the jsfiddle, but having tested the fix within my actual site, it seems to have made no difference.

Comment: It is a little more difficult to replicate in chrome and IE however not impossible. Within firefox the issue is easily created.